# Is there a drupal 7 module to change/filter content in a view via tabs that are not placed inside of the view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a library page with some taxonomy topics(resource types) that are currently being filtered by some really hacky tabs that I would like to replace to do two things:

1) get new, more user friendly tabs, with the capability to be placed outside of the view yet change content inside the said view.

2) be able to have the tabs grouped together in a way I can manipulate them with css.

I am fairly new to the drupal world. What would you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use exposed filter options? 
If so in the advanced tab of the view you have a option 'Exposed form in block' this way your exposed filters will be placed in a seperate block. 
After saving the view you have to enable the block